# When is a Stack allocated variable declared in a function deallocated?

Tags: c++

Clarify my doubt: When is a stack allocated variable declared in a function deallocated?

Comment: I think you should edit it and define it more as a lifetime of a variable. Allocation is usually  associated with dynamic allocation (memory in the heap).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it is not a static variable.
It will be removed from the stack, like all local variables, when it goes out of scope.

In a function that could happen if:
 1. the function returns
 2. unhandled exception

Answer (score 1):

Like Enosh explained. When the variable is out of scope it is removed from the stack, unless it is a member, which still exists, a static or a global variable (which you really shouldn't do).
Here is an example:

```cpp
int foo = 42; // global variable

void doSth(int alpha)
{
    int beta = alpha;
    {
        int gamma = beta;
    } // gamma is deallocated

}   // alpha and beta are deallocated


int main(void)
{
    doSth(foo);
    return 1;
}   // foo is deallocated
```